# How do I make a C program wait for a few seconds?

Tags: c

This is two lines of my code:

```c
    printf("Correct! \nTime took: %d seconds \n", (now - space));
    if (((now + 5) == time(NULL)) && ((now-space) <= 10))
```

Of course it doesn't work as right now is not the 5 seconds to the future, but my problem is to make this wait for 5 seconds instead of going 'Oh, right now is not 5 seconds later so nope, I won't bother doing that.' Is there a way to make this work?
P.S. Someone asked me to write the operating system so it's Windows.

Comment: Something like `now = time(NULL); while (time(NULL) < now + 5);`? Or using [`sleep()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) should be better if your environment supports that.

Comment: What operating system are you working with?  A busy loop will work, but it's not ideal, so something OS-specific will be a better option.

Comment: @StephenNewell I use windows 10

Comment: You probably want to put that detail in your question so that somebody who works on Windows can help.

Comment: @StephenNewell Ok, I've done that.

Comment: [`Sleep()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) is available on Windows.

Comment: The `select()` function maybe a better way, when you want to do something useful with your program. `selects()` waits on 0 or more file descriptors to become ready for reading or writing, a signal arrives or till a timeout runs out. A similar function exist on POSIX systems and Windows. For Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more or less portable `sleep` function using preprocessor directives (time in microseconds):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
//  For Windows (32- and 64-bit)
#   include <windows.h>
#   define SLEEP(msecs) Sleep(msecs)
#elif __unix
//  For linux, OSX, and other unixes
#   define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L // or greater
#   include <time.h>
#   define SLEEP(msecs) do {            \
        struct timespec ts;             \
        ts.tv_sec = msecs/1000;         \
        ts.tv_nsec = msecs%1000*1000;   \
        nanosleep(&ts, NULL);           \
        } while (0)
#else
#   error "Unknown system"
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    SLEEP(1000); // 1 second
    printf("World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

> I use windows 10

Then `Sleep(1000)` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In C >= 11, this should work:

```
#include <threads.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    struct timespec few_seconds = { .tv_sec=3 }; //3 seconds
    for(;;){
        int r = thrd_sleep(&few_seconds,&few_seconds);
        if (!r) break; //sleep finished fully
        if (-1!=r) return perror("thrd_sleep"),1; //some weird error?

        //signal interruption: print the remaining time and continue
        printf("rem=%ld.%09ld\n", (long)few_seconds.tv_sec, (long)few_seconds.tv_nsec);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If your program doesn't handle any signals, a call to `thrd_sleep` without the loop should work too, as then the `thrd_sleep` call shouldn't be interrupted.

Comment: Using "Yoda conditions" in the year 2020, any particular reason why you are?

Answer (score 0):

### For microcontollers

Without timers:

```
void busyWait(unsigned time)
{
  volatile unsigned char dummy=0;
  for(unsigned i=0;i<time;i++)
  {
    //you may need to adjust this value or add more nested loops,
    //depending on the speed of your controller
    for(unsigned j=0;j<10000;j++)
    {
      dummy++;
    }
  }
}
```

This also works on a normal OS, but is probably not the best strategy.

When you want to use timers, you have to study the datasheet of your controller. With a timer, your program can do something else during waiting and the time is probably more precise.